# Tricking Facebook auth into believing that my application is an iPhone

Tags: java, facebook, http, header

I'm  developing an application which will allow users to sign in with their Facebook account. Currently, I'm using [`Eclipse SWT browser`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html) to display the login-browsing window, which works great. However, I'd prefer if this web-browsing window got treated (and therefore styled) as an iPhone. I've tried to force the `HTTP-headers` to mimic the iPhone's; without any change.

My current code looks somewhat like this:

```
String[] headers = { "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3" };
browser.setUrl("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appId&redirect_uri=url&state=state", "", headers);
```

However, the Facebook website STILL realizes that I'm not an iPhone, which makes the output looks like this:

[image]

Whilist I'm looking for this design:

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to include "User-Agent" in the header string?  Eg. `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) ...`. Even so, I would not be surprised if FB *still* detects that you are not a real iPhone browser.